# How can I access static inner class method using object of outer non static class?

Tags: java

How can I access static inner class method using object of outer non static class ?

```
package outer_inner;

public class Outer {

private String s = "Hello";

public void hello() {
System.out.println(s);
}

public static class Inner {

private String name = "World";

public void getName() {
System.out.println(name);
}

}
}
```

I want to access in the below class. how can i do this?

```
package outer_inner;

public class TestOuter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Outer o = new Outer();


Outer.Inner nobj = new Outer.Inner();

}
```

Comment: you need to instantiate object of the inner class which you already did, since your inner class is static its no longer called inner its called nested class. now why not do nobj.getName()?

Comment: @k_hotspot please follow the package naming conventions by reading the name package naming conventions https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: @abcOfJava in what way? You must realize that, as the op is posting a [mcve] specifically for SO, it's perfectly reasonable to not use a reversed FQDN for the package name.

Answer (score 0):

You have already your `Inner` instance in your hand, you can just use it like any other object.

```
Outer.Inner nobj = new Outer.Inner();
nobj.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outer.Inner innerObject = new Outer.Inner(); //Create an instance of static class inner
    innerObject.getName(); //call your method.
}
```